# MessageCreate.js prefix issues with database - Discord.js v13/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js, undefined

I have this code in my messageCreate event:

```
// MODULES
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Levels = require('discord.js-leveling');

// FILES
const Guild = require('../../models/guild');
const config = require('../../files/config.json');
const swearwords = require("../../files/data.json");
const colors = require('../../files/colors.json');

// ERROR MESSAGE

const errorMain = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("There was an error!")
    .setColor(colors.COLOR)
const addedDatabase = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("This server is now added to our database.")
    .setColor(colors.COLOR)

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {

    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const settings = await Guild.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id
    }, (err, guild) => {
        if (err) message.channel.send(errorMain);
        if (!guild) {
            const newGuild = new Guild({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                guildID: message.guild.id,
                prefix: config.PREFIX,
                logChannelID: String,
                enableLog: false,
                enableSwearFilter: true,
                enableMusic: true,
                enableLevel: true,
            });

            newGuild.save()
                .catch(err => message.channel.send(errorMain));
            return message.channel.send({embeds: [addedDatabase]}).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 10000 }))
        }
    });

    // VARIABLES
    const IDGuild = message.guild.id;
    const user = message.author;
    const prefix = settings.prefix;
    const swearFilterOn = settings.enableSwearFilter;

    // LEVEL SYSTEM
    if (settings.enableLevel === "true") {

        const requiredXp = Levels.xpFor(parseInt(user.level) + 1)

        const randomAmountOfXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 1;
        const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomAmountOfXp);

        if (hasLeveledUp) {

            const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);

            const levelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('New Level!')
                .setColor(colors.COLOR)
                .setDescription(`**GG** ${message.author}, you just leveled up to level **${user.level}**!\nContiune to chat to level up again.`)

            const sendEmbed = await message.channel.send({embeds: [levelEmbed]});
        }
    }

    // EXECUTE COMMAND AND SWEARFILTER
    if (swearFilterOn === "true") {
        var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
        for (let i = 0; i < swearwords["swearwords"].length; i++) {
            if (msg.includes(swearwords["swearwords"][i])) {
                message.delete();
                return message.channel.send("Please do not swear.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 }));
            }
        }
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        const command = client.commands.get(cmd) ||
            client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));;

        if (command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord)

    } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        const command = client.commands.get(cmd) ||
            client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));;

        if (command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord)
    }
}
```

And when i send a message right after the bot joines the discord, it gives the error that it cannot read properties of null (reading 'prefix').
The bot crashes, and when it's restarted it works because it has been added to the Database. So how can i fix that when it sends the first message it can still read 'prefix'. its probably a database issue.

I was told that settings.prefix probaly wasn't assinged a value, is there a way to fix this?
I'm using mongodb for my database.

Answer (score 0):

You really should assign the prefix right after the bot joins new server with `guildCreate` event. It may cause some issues if your database is down etc. When you wait till the message event